# Make private keychain specific to an app

Tags: macos, keychain

On Mac OS X, is it possible to create a password protected private keychain such that it is only accessible by a specific application and no other app in that machine.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I figured out this is not really possible just because the way keychains are supposed to work.